# What happens in theory if we focus gravitational waves into a point?

Tags: quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWKFPTgkpXo

Basically inspired by this video and its comparison with wormholes.
While many other questions on the site have already covered the weak strength of gravitational waves and hence hinting the experimental feasibility, what will happen in theory when there are gravitational waves of sufficient energy to converge to a point. Do we end up with a black hole similar to how a kugleblitz works or we don't know because at the focal point, the strength of gravity will be so strong that it is no longer obeying the weak field limit and hence require a quantum gravity description?

The only thing I am certain without doing some pretty computationally intensive numerical modelling is that since gravitational waves are nonlinear, they cannot be expected to just add up in superposition, so the resulting wave may not be a spike wave.

Comment: Most physicists do not agree with safesphere’s comment. In previous arguments he has refused to state his argument in an answer where it can be voted on because he knows it will be downvoted. A kugelblitz is mainstream physics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelblitz_(astrophysics)

Comment: @safesphere https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/479299/does-kinetic-energy-warp-spacetime . . . but the stress energy tensor does include kinetic energy/momentum in it. Photons do have momentum or such inherent energy. . . energy in the stress energy tensor warps spacetime. . . so a Kugleblitz is therefore not a myth in your sense. Do you have an argument as to the stress-energy tensor not having components relating to time dependency of energy/momentum distributions?

Comment: @safesphere I'm not sure that it really cancels out as in the case of approximate gravito-electromagnetism the gravito-magnetic effect really only arises in the case of relative, perhaps constant velocity, motion or non-zero angular momentum. . . however. . . it still arises. In the rest frame of the object you'd observe only a gravito-electric field but in relative motion you'd also observe the other 'field'. So wouldn't a photon have a permanent gravito-magnetic component?

Comment: @safesphere "A bullet with a negligible mass doesn't curve spacetime in the rest frame and doesn't attract nearby objects." Let's stick to the inherent energy of the object rather than to its mass. Anything with negligible energy and substitution into the stress energy tensor will lead to results as if it were in say. . . just in minkowski spacetime with other non-interacting particles of negligible momentum-energy. However, what if this particle/photon didn't have negligible energy content (E=hv) or (E=mc^2).

Comment: @safesphere For-going these assumptions of how negligible it is any energy content or momentum will influence its gravito-electric or gravito-magnetic fields. I'm curious then? What happens when a photon/electromagnetic field has the energy content of the rest energy of the Earth then would it have any curvature associated with it within GR? How you know this to be or not be the case after said substitution?